# How to add zombie arms to enemies in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, trigonometry

I'm making a game with HTML canvas (not WEBGL). I have zombies that go to the center of the screen, but for now they are just circles. I want to give them two arms, like the arms players have in surviv.io. I have looked at this question: [Moving an object in a circular path](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9607/moving-an-object-in-a-circular-path/9610). I don't know what trigonometry to use to calculate the angle. Here is my code:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Enemy(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = 5;
  this.color = `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 360)},50%,50%)`;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.draw = () => {
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.fill();
  }
}
var enemy = new Enemy(0, 0);

function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var angle = Math.atan2(canvas.height / 2 - enemy.y, canvas.width / 2 - enemy.x);
  enemy.vx = Math.cos(angle);
  enemy.vy = Math.sin(angle);
  enemy.draw();
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop)
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'>
```

I want the arms facing the center, and I want them to move when the enemy changes direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the game you mention, but on a quick image search it looks like the entity arms are represented by circles, either holding a gun or in resting positions when not holding anything. Regardless, the basic approach is pretty much the same:

```
const angle = Math.atan2(this.vy, this.vx);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(
  this.x + Math.cos(angle + armOffsetRadians) * armDistance,
  this.y + Math.sin(angle + armOffsetRadians) * armDistance,
  this.r / 2, 
  0, Math.PI * 2
);
ctx.stroke();
```

An alternative approach is to use something like

```
ctx.save();
ctx.transform(entity.x, entity.y);
ctx.rotate(entityAngle);
// draw the entity facing a neutral direction -- rotation is already handled
ctx.restore();
```

Here's a naive example of the top approach running:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Enemy(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = 5;
  this.color = `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 360)},50%,50%)`;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.move = () => {
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;
  };
  this.draw = ctx => {
    const armOffsetRadians = 0.5;
    const armDistance = 8;
    const angle = Math.atan2(this.vy, this.vx);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(
      this.x + Math.cos(angle + armOffsetRadians) * armDistance,
      this.y + Math.sin(angle + armOffsetRadians) * armDistance,
      this.r / 2, 
      0, Math.PI * 2
    );
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(
      this.x + Math.cos(angle - armOffsetRadians) * armDistance, 
      this.y + Math.sin(angle - armOffsetRadians) * armDistance,
      this.r / 2, 
      0, Math.PI * 2
    );
    ctx.fill();
  };
}
var enemy = new Enemy(0, 0);
var mouseX = canvas.width / 2;
var mouseY = canvas.height / 2;
var canRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  mouseX = e.clientX - canRect.left;
  mouseY = e.clientY - canRect.top;
});

function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var angle = Math.atan2(
    mouseY - enemy.y, 
    mouseX - enemy.x
  );
  enemy.vx = Math.cos(angle);
  enemy.vy = Math.sin(angle);
  enemy.move();
  enemy.draw(context);
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'>
```

I couldn't resist passing the context in as a parameter to `Enemy.draw` -- if you rely on globals, the function breaks if the name or scope changes.

I also separated `move` and `draw` functions. This is good engineering practice in general, since functions should only do one thing, but it's even more important in an animation, because rendering is a totally distinct step from updating positions, computing collision, etc. The typical approach is to loop over all entities and update their positions, handle collisions and complete a full logical update on the game, then loop over the game state in a separate pass and render everything by z-index.

You can see 4 arms when the enemy stops. That's because it's moving back and forth really fast on the destination coordinates. You'll probably want to add a condition not to move if the entity's distance to the destination is below a certain threshold to avoid this "spazzing out" effect.

Beyond that, you can see a lot of repeated work happening here. I'm not sure how you ultimately want to design your game, but adding a setter for an enemy's angle would avoid multiple calls to `Math.atan2`. Setting `enemy.vx` and `enemy.vy` should probably be internal to the enemy and occur when `setAngle` is called.

I'll leave this design suggestion as an exercise since your primary question is a trigonometric one and I don't want to assume too much.